# Why does my VS Code not recognize 'python' as an internal or external command

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

so I just considered using VS Code for writing python as i'm settling into programming. After following the full guide here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial and everything seemed ok.

But my code wont run, but runs well in my PyCharm but on VS Code it pops this error below:

"'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

I have followed threads here advising reboot of computer and all but its not working for me, I would love to at least know what the problem is because my decision to use VSC is because i'd like to have one IDE that supports more languages so that write in one place or at least a few IDEs.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can run `python` in the console, right? If not I'd suggest to check your PATH variables

Comment: Did you set Python in your PATH or add it as the [interpreter in settings as shown in the docs you linked](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_select-a-python-interpreter)?

Comment: @Axiumin_ let me confirm, not sure anymore, last path i set was for java

Comment: @LinkBerest I'd comfirm path and get back.

Comment: @Axiumin_ I have set the PATH and restarted my computer yet its still not recognized when i typed python in command prompt

Comment: Okay, that last thread was way too old: SuperUser has a better answer for this, see [How do I set system environmental variables in Win10](https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10)

Answer (score 0):

thanks, I've fixed it by uninstalling the existing python and reinstalling latest version, most importantly i realized i was adding a new path instead of editing the existing path. In recent windows clicking edit on the existing path will open a new dailog where you can then add a new path, that will be added to the existing path. Then I restarted my computer and then typed python --version at command prompt and there it was :) by the way this link (geek-university.com/python/add-python-to-the-windows-path) was most helpful but you have to do it as i described.